# ordinary differential equation equals to non zero integers

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$f ' '(x)+4f '(x)+f(x)=3\qquad   f(0)=2\qquad   f'(0)=1$$

Our teacher only taught us how to solve ODE equation $= 0$.
which $α^2+4α+1=0$ but in this case I cant write like this since the equation $= 3$.
$b^2-4ac = 12$. two roots are $-2+3^{1/2}$ and $-2-3^{1/2}$.
how do I deal with this?
it is clearly not $f(x) = c_1e^{-2+3^{1/2}}+c_2e^{-2-3^{1/2}}$ in this case .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if $f(x)$ solves $f''(x)+4f'(x)+f(x)=3$ and $g(x)$ solves $g''(x)+4g'(x)+g(x)=0$ then $h=f+g$ also solves the original differential equation because $h''+4h'+h=3$

You know how to find $g(x)$ - as a linear combination of two basic solutions of the homogeneous $(=0)$ equation.

You will find that $f(x)=3$ is a particular solution. Add the general solution of the homogeneous equation, and use the two boundary conditions to determine the specific solution you need.

You will need to get some feeling for the different kinds of functions and circumstances which affect the form you should be testing to solve the inhomogeneous form - all kinds of functions can appear on the right-hand side.

Comment: It is really helpful. wow great help thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take one more derivative of both side and get $a^3+4a^2+a=0$...and use your initial condition.

Comment: OH i see. thanks

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: but it goes back to a2+4a+1=0 which is not right

Comment: You shoul take all roots, including a=0.

Comment: you will get $f(x)=c_1e^{x_1}+c_2e^{x_2}+c_3$ Where $x_1, x_2$ are roots of $a^2+4a+1$

Comment: ok that means guess the number of f(x)

Comment: let me give you an exircise,solve same equation when it is equal to $sin(x)$